# Why is a negative projection vector possible?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I'm leaving the question here but my comment answers most of what I was confused about.

The only thing I'm still curious about is why the dot product is restricted from 0 to pi.

I understand that the dot product formula is $a \cdot b = |a||b|\cos(\theta)$ and that to get the projection of a onto b, is to get the length of a along b like the shadow of it.

So $\cos(\theta) = |a_{\text{par}}| / |a| \implies |a| \cdot \cos(\theta) = |a_{\text{par}}|$, where $\cos(\theta)$ may be negative. I'm just wondering why sites list the restriction of θ∈[0,π] since it looks like it invalidates the absolute value. I'm guessing it's negative, despite being an absolute value, due to being the length of the shadow of vector a of which to go backwards in order to reach where b and a meet. Vector a is behind b.

I've noticed it also becomes possible for $|a_{\text{parallel}}| = (a \cdot b) / (|b|)$ to similarly end up as a negative value as well. $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle = a; \langle -1,1,-1 \rangle = b$ and is one example. Theta is $109.47$ degrees.

Is the absolute value being invalidated and what does it mean to get a negative vector projection?negative value as well. 
<1,1,1> = a <-1,1,-1> = b and  is one example. Theta is 109.47 degrees.

Is the absolute value being invalidated and what does it mean to get a negative vector projection?

Comment: How do you get $\cos\theta = |a_{\rm par}|/|a|$ from $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos\theta$? What is $a_{\rm par}$ for you?

Comment: apar is supposed to be the projection of a onto b like the length of the shadow of a casted onto b. From theta from 0 to pi/2, the cosine relation is describes the magnitude of vector apar as "adjacent" and vector a as the "hypotenuse." Vectors apar and b are on the same line and are in the same direction. apar is the component of a that is parallel to b. I then proceeded to substitute the cosine relationship into the dot product formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean that $\mathbf a_\text{parallel}$ is the projection of the vector $\mathbf a$ onto the vector $\mathbf b.$

A typical equation giving the projection of $\mathbf a$ onto $\mathbf b$
is this:

$$
\mathbf a_\text{parallel}
  = \frac{\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b}{\lVert\mathbf b\rVert^2} \mathbf b.
$$

Here's a way to build up this formula.
Let's start with a unit vector in the same direction as $\mathbf b$:
$$
\hat{\mathbf b} = \frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf b\rVert} \mathbf b.
$$
Multiply this by any positive number $r,$ and you get a vector of length $r$ in the direction of $\mathbf b.$
The clue for dealing with negative numbers is that negating a vector makes it go in the opposite direction.
So if $r$ is a positive number, $r\mathbf b$ is in the same direction as $\mathbf b,$ but $-r\mathbf b$ is in the opposite direction from $\mathbf b.$
That is, multiply by a negative number $-r,$ get a vector in the opposite direction.

Next, we use the dot product formula to derive the fact that
$$
\lVert\mathbf a\rVert \cos(\theta)
 = \frac{\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b}{\lVert\mathbf b\rVert}.
$$

Finally, to get the projection of $\mathbf a$ onto $\mathbf b,$
we take the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf b}$ in the direction of $\mathbf b,$
and multiply by $\lVert\mathbf a\rVert \cos(\theta)$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf a_\text{parallel}
&= \left(\lVert\mathbf a\rVert \cos(\theta)\right)\hat{\mathbf b} \\
&= \left(\frac{\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b}{\lVert\mathbf b\rVert}\right)
   \left(\frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf b\rVert} \mathbf b\right) \\
&= \frac{\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b}{\lVert\mathbf b\rVert^2} \mathbf b.
\end{align}

When we do this, the fact that $\cos(\theta)$ can be negative is a *useful feature* of the formula, not an annoyance to be worked around.
We get negative values of $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b$
when the angle between the vectors is obtuse
and *only* when the angle is obtuse.
The cases where the angle is obtuse are exactly the cases in which we want the projection vector to go in the opposite direction from $\mathbf b,$
which is exactly what multiplication of $\mathbf b$ by a negative scalar makes the projection vector do.

Answer (score 0):

$ \cos(\theta) = -|a parallel| / |a| $ seems to be the equation that is supposed to be used for theta>pi/2. Doesn't seem to be any issues with absolute value when this is used. Makes sense as the adjacent value should now be negative.